# AArch64 memory synchronization operations on multiply-mapped addresses

Tags: caching, arm64, memory-barriers, memory-model, virtual-address-space

Suppose I have two pages that map to the same physical memory. Would an acquire operation (or fence) on a virtual address in one page properly synchronize with a release operation (or fence) on a virtual address in the other? Secondly, would cache maintenance operations (`dc`, `ic`), too, work with such multiply-mapped memory?

In other words...

- ...would a `stlr` (or `dmb ishst` if fence) on one core to one page properly synchronize with `ldar` (or `dmb ishld` if fence) on another core to the other page?
- ...would a `dc whatever` on one virtual address have the same effect as a `dc whatever` on the other?

Comment: I'm pretty sure yes; otherwise AArch64 would get mentioned as an example of C++ `std::atomic` being "address-free" when `is_always_lock_free` is true.  AFAIK, mainstream ISAs generally synchronize on physical address, not virtual.  (And this applies even when the same thread is accessing both mapping, at least on x86 but I think on most ISAs.)

Comment: data cache uses physical tagging, while instruction cache uses virtual tagging on AArch64 if I remember correctly. If you are trying to sync multiple cores it's commonly done with 'spinlock'. Also depending on chip you are using cache coherence might be implemented in hardware, therefore eliminating need in cache maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

As to memory ordering, yes, this is fine.  The ARMv8 memory model is defined in terms of reads and writes of a *Location*, which is defined as "a byte that is associated with an address in the **physical**  address space".  See B2.3.1 in the Architecture Reference Manual, version H.a.  (Older versions left out the "physical" part so it seems someone noticed that this was ambiguous.)

Likewise, an exclusive load `ldxr` says in the manual that it marks the **physical** address as an exclusive access.

Note that if this weren't the case, then on typical OSes, shared memory between processes (e.g. `shmget`, `mmap(MAP_SHARED)`, etc) would be unusable, as the shared mappings are normally at different virtual addresses in the different processes.

I can't answer the part about cache right now.